# Three.js: display the object in the middle of the scene

Tags: three.js

I tried to load 3D model by using OBJLoader and it successed.The model is drawn with a three-dimensional modeling software and converts to .obj format by using conversion software. Because the model is absolute positioning, there are always problems displaying the model.

In this case, how can i display the object in the middle of the scene and make the model look normal?

Would you give me some help with trying to get this working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few avenues of thought, but I don't know exactly what you mean by "there are always problems displaying the model" and "make the model look normal".

In my (small) experience of Three.js, I have stumbled upon basically two main categories of issues :
- Positionning, ie you end up with improper coordinates, like too large/small of out of bounds : for that, study your model, compute and display the Bounding Box and/or Bounding Sphere (try to write a log in the browser's error window), and adjust camera according to the values found,
- Lights, sometimes you got a black-on-black display that is nearly invisible : for that, begin with both materials and lights with ambient at {1,1,1}, so the models appear clearly as pure white on a black background,  then refine material and lights to give the desired effects.

Can't say much more for now, until I know more precisely what is your question...

Small code for outputting an error log :

```
function log(msg) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }, 0);
}
```

Use like this :

```
log('Radius = ' + radius);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My qustion is how can I display the model in the middle of the scene/screen every time I load it. And I want to know if there is a mechanism in Three.js that can support it. Thank you again!

Comment: From your comment, I assume your lighting is correct : you actually can see the object on the screen, but it is not at the correct position with respect to the camera. So you should try to compute the object's Bounding Box, position the camera at a suitable distance from the BB center, depending on the focal, then have it look at the BB center. Three.js has functions supporting that. What do you use for controls ? or if you don't use a Controls utility, look at the Camera class and its derived classes.